# If $x = \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{\sqrt{2} + 1}$, what is $\frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{\sqrt{2} - 1}$ in terms of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I could not manage to solve this easy question on my test book.
Sorry the image is in Turkish.

[image: question_about_radical_expression]

I will try to translate it, it says if 
$$x = \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{\sqrt{2} + 1}$$ 
what is 
$$\frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{\sqrt{2} - 1}$$ 
in terms of $x$?

I do not know if I translated it well, but thanks for any help you can provide anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x=\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{\sqrt 2+1}$$
Multiply both sides by $\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{\sqrt 2-1}$
$$x\cdot\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{\sqrt 2-1}=\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{\sqrt 2+1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{\sqrt 2-1}$$
Use that $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$
$$x\cdot\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{\sqrt 2-1}=\frac{3-1}{2-1}=2$$
Finally, divide by $x$
$$\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{\sqrt 2-1}=\frac{2}{x}$$

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped.This solution is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Multiply 
$$x = \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{\sqrt{2} + 1}$$
by 
$$\frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{\sqrt{3} - 1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2} - 1}$$
then compare the result with
$$\frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{\sqrt{2} - 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let ${\displaystyle x:={\sqrt{3}+1\over\sqrt{2}+1}}$ and ${\displaystyle y:={\sqrt{3}-1\over\sqrt{2}-1}}$. Then ${\displaystyle x\cdot y={2\over1}}$, hence ${\displaystyle y={2\over x}}$.